# How to configure the logging framework in Spring-Boot?

Tags: java, spring, log4j, spring-boot

How can I tell `Spring-Boot` which logging framework to use? (I want to use log4j2).

In 1.1.9.RELEASE I just had a `log4j2.xml` in my classpath and the logging worked.

Now I upgraded to spring-boot-1.2.0.RELEASE, and my loggers do not work anymore! Maybe I have to configure the logging framework to be used explicit?

I'm using `org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.getRootLogger()` for logging, maybe this is wrong?

Answer (score 2):

See the docs: http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-logging.html#howto-configure-log4j-for-logging

Just change the POM

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Hm that does still not help. I'm using `org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.getRootLogger()` logger object. Maybe this is inappropriate? Which is the correct class for eg `log.info()` when using spring-boot with log4j2?

Comment: Why don't you try using `org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(Class<?>)`? I think it's supposed to be a dependency, the slf4j jars, for spring-boot

Comment: Because I want to use log4j2 explicit to enable async logging.

Comment: @membersound I would try `Logger.getLogger("perfLog")`

Answer (score 0):

You *should* be using SFL4J which is a level of abstraction around the actual logging implementation used. if you configure your POM as above, and include the appropriate log4j configuration in src/main/resources, and log using a org.slf4j.Logger then you should be fine